# $error variable not available in modules?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've grown very fond of using `try..catch` statements in Powershell scripts (specially when calling external programs/COM objects etc), and then use the automatic `$error` variable for error handling.

My problem is that I've found that when encapsualting such methods in modules, the `$error` variable doesn't work anymore. I guess this has something to do with what invocation you're actually running when calling a function from within a module, but it's infuriating anyway. Does anyone here know why, or even better: have a solution?

I do have a workaround: using `Invoke-Expression` with the `-errorVariable` parameter for making any external calls, but this is rather complicated - and not always fool proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using the $_ variable within the catch block will do?

Comment: Works, kind of:
`New-Module MyMod { function div { param ([int]$i) try { 10/$i } catch { Write "`$_: $_"; Write $error[0].exception } } }`
Turns out the $_ is localized (I got an "error" in Swedish ;). And it still lacks the $error functionality.

Comment: No, what is happening is that you are converting $_ (an exception object) to a string, so you only get the message.  Try `$_ | get-member`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
`New-Module MyMod { function div { param ([int]$i) try { 10/$i } catch { if ($_ -match "divide by zero") { Write "Can't divide by zero, silly!" }  }  }  }`